# Match single digits only sed

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I have to make a regex to match one digit only. 
it should match 7 and a7b but not 77.
I made this but it doesn`t seem to work in sed.

```
(?<![\d])(?<![\S])[1](?![^\s.,?!])(?!^[\d]) 
(?<![\d])(?<!^[\a-z])\d(?![^a-z])(?!^[\d])
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

I need to replace only 1-digit numbers with something like

```
sed 's/regex/@/g' file //regex to match "1"
```

file content

```
1 2 3 4 5 11 1
agdse1tg1xw 
6 97 45 12
```

Should become

```
 @ 2 3 4 5 11 @ 
 agdse@tg@xw 
 6 97 45 12
```

Comment: sed only support BRE and ERE. But you might be able to use `grep -oP` or `grep -P` to use PCRE.

Comment: Why don't 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6 in your example get converted to `@`s? Are you trying to convert 1-digit numbers or the digit 1?

Comment: The edit has made this question unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you show in the Example in your question is:

```
$ sed -r 's/(^|[^0-9])1([^0-9]|$)/\1@\2/g' file
@ 2 3 4 5 11 @
agdse@tg@xw
6 97 45 12
```

but that only works because you didn't have `1 1` in your data. If you did you'd need 2 passes:

```
$ echo '1 1' | sed -r 's/(^|[^0-9])[0-9]([^0-9]|$)/\1@\2/g'
@ 1

$ echo '1 1' | sed -r 's/(^|[^0-9])[0-9]([^0-9]|$)/\1@\2/g; s/(^|[^0-9])[0-9]([^0-9]|$)/\1@\2/g'
@ @
```

and if you wanted to do that for any single digit it would be:

```
$ sed -r 's/(^|[^0-9])[0-9]([^0-9]|$)/\1@\2/g; s/(^|[^0-9])[0-9]([^0-9]|$)/\1@\2/g' file
@ @ @ @ @ 11 @
agdse@tg@xw
@ 97 45 12
```

Comment: this is what i was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Input**

```
a77
a7b
2ab
882
9
abcfg9
9fg
ab9
```

**Script**

```
sed -En '/^[^[:digit:]]*[[:digit:]]{1}[^[:digit:]]*$/p' filename
```

**Output**

```
a7b
2ab
9
abcfg9
9fg
ab9
```

Comment: Worth to mention that you should use `-E` on OSX and that GNU sed should support `-E` as well, even though it's not mentioned in `man sed`

Comment: `*` will make both digits optional matching `77`

Comment: Single digit is not matched with this pattern.

Comment: @andlrc : Thanks for the update. :-)

Comment: @Kenavoz : It is, now ;)

Comment: @rock321987 : Pasted the wrong stuff.. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

sed only supports [BRE](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html#bre) and [ERE](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html#ere), but you can enable [PCRE](http://www.regular-expressions.info/pcre.html) with `grep -P`:

```
% printf 'a77\na7b\n2ab\n82\n' | grep -P '(?<!\d)\d(?!\d)'
a7b
2ab
```

grep will as demonstrated print matched lines, but have an option to print the match only:

```
% printf 'a77\na7b\n2ab\n82\n' | grep -oP '(?<!\d)\d(?!\d)'
7
2
```

Comment: this is what i need but it kinda has to be made with sed because i have to replace the digit

Comment: @Restal How do you feel about adding Perl to your dependencies: `perl -pe s/(?<!\d)\d(?!\d)/replacement/g input_file`

Comment: unfortunately is not acceptable as i have to make it using sed

Comment: @Restal You can modify Kenavoz answer to match your needs. Just make use of capturing groups: `\(...\)` which will store the captured value in `\1`, `\2`, ...